# How to check if a particular key exists in all of the objects in JSON array using dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to check if a key exists in all of the objects in a JSON array.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "document_id": 5,
    "doc_number": "US-MULE-2200005",
    "expiration_date": null,
    "status": "Fail",
    "error": "UNAUTHORIZED"
  },
    {
    "document_id": 5,
    "doc_number": "US-MULE-2200006",
    "expiration_date": null,
    "status": "Success"
  }
]
```

Above is the sample payload I get and I want to check if "error" key exists in the array, if exists I want to set a flag as true else false. In above example since its not available in one object I want to set the flag as false

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use the [every() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-every) from the array module. Then in the condition use the [key present selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors).

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
payload every ($.error?)
```